# Vue 2 v-model data not binding and removing property

Tags: ajax, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a bound select to nested data:

```
    <select class="form-control" v-model="user_profile.sport.sport_id">
      <option v-for="sport in sport_information.sports" :value="sport.sport_id">{{ sport.sport_name }}</option>
    </select>
```

The data is received from an AJAX call.  In this case, user_profile.sport.sport_id is:

```
{ "sport_id": 2, "name": "Baseball" }
```

But after loading the page I lose the sport_id

```
{"name": "Baseball" }
```

I believe it is because the option values (sport_information.sports) are also loaded with JSON.  So when Vue tries to bind the sport_id value, there might be none value for the select, and it removes the property.

```
      this.$parent.callAPI('POST', '/Business/GetSportInformation.ashx', data).then(function (sResponse) {
        self.sport_information = Object.assign({}, sResponse.data)
```

And callAPI uses vue-resourse:

```
export default {
name: 'App',
data: function () {
  return {
    section: 'Head',
    version: '0.10.0',
    callingAPI: false,
    serverURI: 'http://mywebservice.net/API',
    caller: this.$http
  }
},
methods: {
  callAPI: function (method, url, data) {
    this.callingAPI = true
    url = this.serverURI + url // if no url is passed then inheret local server URI
    return this.caller.post(url, data)
  },
```

How does one handle data binding of AJAX sourced data in selects?

Comment: How do you initiate vuejs instance? Is it aware of all the model properties?

Comment: Yes, it is aware of all the properties and sport defaults to { "sport_id": 0, "name": "" }

Comment: Can you please add some example data at [http://www.mocky.io/](http://www.mocky.io/) and send me the link? Then I can create a demo to see the issue.

Comment: Can you add your code, how you are defining data, how Ajax call is happening,

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The API call populating the dropdown options would respond after the API call that bound data to the select.  So the data binds to a select with no option values and the sport_id property is removed from the object.

After the select options are populated, if I change the select value the sport_id property is readded to the object with the current value of the select.

I had to make sure that I populate the select before binding data in order for the page to properly load the form.